# scalability issues with video encoding on webserver

Tags: ffmpeg, scalability, video-encoding

On a web application that im creating the user is allowed to upload a video. The video is converted to x264 using ffmpeg for iOS playback. So if there are too many users thats going to kill the web server.

I'm thinking about something like this. Have a few encoding servers for the application and the application on receiving the video file uploads to any one encoding server and the encoding server encodes the video and uploads it back to the web server.

Are there any other solutions preferably which wont increase the response time for the user? The user has to see the preview of the video as soon as the upload process finishes.

The client does not want any 3rd party video encoding services. We have negotiated this many times but they do not want this.

Comment: How many uploads are you expecting to have? Chances are you are doing a premature optimization. And you can run multiple ffmpeg processes at once. Just use a multi-core processor.

Comment: The client expects 1000's of simultaneous users. In the application the video addition is a optional feature. So many may not opt for a video. Some may upload a video file, some may record from webcam. Some may just use youtube links (in case of youtube no encoding etc). Since the platform is not live im not sure about the actual numbers.

Comment: You don't mention format, is there any possibility that the uploaded video's can just be played natively using a custom player of some type. what are the input formats allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Resque to queue up encoding jobs. Then you can scale the number of processes/machines based on the size of the queue on Resque.